# How to adjust forecast to special events and marketing campaign

Tags: time-series, forecasting

This is not a mathematical question. Last April our bus company went for an all out marketing campaign with special discount schemes as well. The result, we sold 17K tickets instead of forecasted 10K (under normal circumstances). Now this April month's data is quite high and disturbing the forecast for other months, and perhaps will affect the forecasting for next year. What is the industry standard to resolve such problems.

a) to drop the actual value and continue with forecasted value ? b) to use a cut off value that marketing people were expecting to achieve? c) to continue with the actual as is, as this is the true value ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you now all discount (sales) dates from past and the ones that you will have in the future you could use them as regressors. For example,you could create a data if there is a discount 1, 0 otherwise. You could use `auto.arima()` or `stlf()` with `methods=”arima”` or `nnetar()` with `xreg` option, and use this dates as regressors.